# PS3 Eye USB Camera Not Detected - Raspbian Stretch

Tags: camera, raspbian-stretch, webcam

After updating to Raspbian Stretch (kernel 4.14.90-v7+), my Playstation 3 Eye camera is no longer detected on any of the three Pi3 Model Bs that I have. `lsusb` does not report the device and `dmesg` shows no error. `vcgencmd get_camera` > `supported=0 detected=0`.

I tried adding to boot modules, `bcm2835-v4l2`, and `gspca_ov534` as suggested in some Ubuntu forums, but none of these helps. I have tried the camera with and without a USB power hub, again with no success. The problem persists on fresh installation of Stretch.

The camera works fine in Ubuntu 18.04 and Debian Stretch on amd64 machines. On my Pi, an old Creative Webcam is detected and works.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks and Happy Holidays!

Comment: My PS3 camera works on my Pi3 with the latest Raspbian Stretch. Are you able to do a fresh install of the latest Raspbian Stretch rather than an update?

Comment: Yes. My PS3 fails on fresh installations of Raspbian Stretch. I have a machine running Debian Stretch (amd64), PS3 Eye works fine on it.

Comment: CoderMike:
That your PS3 Eye works Raspbian Stretch gives me hope! Did it work out of box? Do I need to modify any settings in  /boot/config.txt? Could you please tell me what driver module is being loaded and used? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, worked out of the box. Didn't modify anything. Away from home at the moment - will try and remember to check when home.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply in the middle of holidays. When you get to it, could you also please check for me the kernel version? Thanks.

Comment: uname -a : Linux raspberrypi 4.14.79-v7+ #1159 SMP Sun Nov 4 17:50:20 GMT 2018 armv7l GNU/Linux

Comment: Thanks. Have been traveling, and will try to get to this today.

Comment: I tried on an rpi with the same kernel as yours, but it still fails to detect the PS3Eye. This applies to fresh installations of Raspbian Stretch on Pi3B and Pi3B+. Any suggestions as to where should look for what I could be doing wrong? Thanks.